# Compare set of model instances with their conterparts in DB | Django

Tags: django

I have a question reg. comparing big set of model instances with data in DB.

for example I have a model with 5 fields:

```
model Foo(models.Model)
    fields1 = models.Integerfield()
    fields2 = models.Integerfield()
    fields3 = models.Integerfield()
    fields4 = models.Integerfield()
    fields5 = models.Integerfield()
    
    class Meta:
        unique_together = (‘field1', 'field2’,)
```

and I have 400.000 model `Foo` entries saved in DB.

Also I have 400.000 +/- few instances in memory(in python)of the same model generated from internet CSV file (without pk set).

Question is – what is the most efficient way to do following:

1)If instance in python equal to same instance in DB – keep instance in DB.

2)If instance in python not equal to instance in DB – update instance in DB.

3. If instance in python does not coincide to any instances in DB – write it to DB.
4. If no instances in python coincide to particular instance in DB – delete instance from DB.

Its should be bulk operations or RAW SQL as sample size is quite big.

Thank you.

PS. What i do now - delete all, reset counter, write all again to db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hoping you use Django>=2.2. Try this script,

```
import csv, os
from your_app.models import Foo

def get_db_object_from_file_object(file_object):
    return Foo(
        field1=file_object[0],
        field2=file_object[1],
        field3=file_object[2],
        field4=file_object[3],
        field5=file_object[4],
    )

def update_db_object_from_file_object(db_object, file_object):
    db_object.field1 = file_object[0]
    db_object.field2 = file_object[1]
    db_object.field3 = file_object[2]
    db_object.field4 = file_object[3]
    db_object.field5 = file_object[4]

with open("<filename.csv>") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    eof = os.fstat(f.fileno()).st_size

    file_objects = {(each[0], each[1]): each for each in reader}
    db_objects = {
        (each.field1, each.field2): each 
        for each in Foo.objects.filter(
            field1__in=(each[0] for each in next_lines),
            field2__in=(each[1] for each in next_lines)
        )
    }
        
    to_create = []
    to_update = []
    for pair, obj in file_objects.items():
        if pair not in db_objects:
            to_create.append(obj)
        else:
           update_db_object_from_file_object(db_objects[pair], obj)
           to_update.append(db_objects[pair])
           del db_objects[pair]

    Foo.objects.bulk_create(to_create)
    Foo.objects.bulk_update(to_update, ["field1", "field2", "field3", "field4", "field5"])
    Foo.objects.filter(id__in=[each.pk for each in db_objects.values()])
```

Comment: Smart!, need to check it